# android - linked-resources when building from command line

Tags: java, android, ant, command-line

During development, our Android app is built using Eclipse (ADT). We use an eclipse feature called Linked Resources, which allows eclipse to compile files outside of the source tree.

It works well on eclipse, but when trying to compile from the command line (using `android update project` and `ant`), ant/javac won't find the linked resources (as they are defined in the eclipse project).

How can I make it work? Do I need to manually add the additional source dir to build.xml (which was auto-generated by android)? Is there an android setting I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the paths of the extra source code in the source.dir line of ant.properties in your project directory. Something like this:

source.dir=src;../ExtraSource;../MoreSource/java

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21205 for more discussion. Apparently they took this feature out at some point but it looks like they have put it back in since then.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using referencing library? If so, you need to tell ant where it can find the referencing library (typically in project.properties)

```
android.library.reference.1=/pathToReferenceLibrary
```

A referencing library is where you want to keep all classes and resouces that you want to reuse between different android projects.

Comment: Seems like the way to go, except that I don't want to create a new android project for that - I want it built as part of my app. There's a good reason for that.